# Alocation instrument in Profiler not showing Application level classes

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, profiler, xcode-instruments

I'm running into an issue using Xcode 6.3 Beta 3 where Profiler is not showing any of my custom application classes in the list of allocations:

[image]

I have multiple classes that contain the word *Post* but none of them show up in the allocation summary, even though they are definitely being displayed on the screen.

I've set the App target up to use *Debug* mode when running in Profiler so I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

When searching in the allocation list I can see allocations performed by the class I'm looking for, but no trace of an allocation history of the class itself:

[image]

**Any idea which setting could be wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Update: with the release of Xcode 6.3 (6D570) I can get memory profiling to work as expected on the device:

[image]

However, it is **still not working on the simulator**.